# Bootstrap - CSS - Container now showing when nav is there

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having a slight issue. I am trying to make a layout that has a navigation in the top right. And have the content inside a container below it.

The issue is that the container with the content appears inside the nav bar. I cannot seem to figure out where I am going wrong with this. The code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="misc"><a href="../navbar/">About</a></li>
            <li class="misc"><a href="../navbar/">Servo</a></li>
            <li class="misc"><a href="../navbar/">Spindle</a></li>
            <li class="misc"><a href="../navbar/">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="misc small"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px;"></span></a></li>
            <li class="misc small"></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


  <div class="container-fluid">
    CONTENT
  </div>
```

And the JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

As you can see, I cannot see the content, if I inspect the element it is appearing inside the actual navbar. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Your content doesn't match the jsfiddle link. Please update as necessary!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the class `collapse` class added after the `navbar-collapse`. Just remove the class and you will see the naviagtion.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown active">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Getting started <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download">Download Bootstrap</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Examples</li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template">Basic template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/">Starter template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/">Grids</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/">Jumbotron</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/">Navbar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/">Sign-in page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/">Sticky footer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/">Offcanvas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/">Carousel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/">Theme</a></li>                        
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Compatibility</li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration">Migrating from 2.x to 3.0</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers">Browser support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties">Third party support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/components">Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/customize">Customize</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.0</h1>
        <p class="lead">Starter template with CSS and JS included.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#fork">Fork this fiddle</a></p>
      </div>
</div>
```